# Trying to access JSON Object using key

Tags: jquery, json

This is my code that stores JSON in a `var`:

```
var analysed Data = {
  "Wednesday": {
    "OTHERS": {
      "count": 1,
      "response Time": 234
    },
      "URGENT": {
      "count": 15,
      "response Time": 68
    },
      "NORMAL": {
      "count": 10,
      "response Time": 120
    }
  },
    "Thursday": {
    "OTHERS": {
      "count": 1,
      "response Time": 234
    },
      "URGENT": {
      "count": 15,
      "responseTime": 68
    },
      "NORMAL": {
      "count": 10,
      "responseTime": 120
    }
  },
  "Tuesday": {
    "OTHERS": {
      "count": 1,
      "response Time": 5
    },
      "URGENT": {
      "count": 15,
      "response Time": 68
    },
      "NORMAL": {
      "count": 10,
      "response Time": 120
    }
  }
}
```

***Question:***

Please suggest me ways to access them using the `key`. I need to get the response time for each keyword like `normal`. This is urgent, for your information.

I am supposed achieve this usingjQuery and add the response time to get the `avg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have json object in JavaScript you can access to keys and values:

```
$.each(myObject, function (key, val) {

    // See key and value:
    alert(key + ': ' + val.URGENT.count);

    // See keys for each object:
    $.each(Object.keys(val), function (key, val) {
        alert(key + ': ' + val);
    });
});
```